# WSO2 ESB Message JMS Producer Exception:

Tags: apache-axis, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I have Created a queue named NewJMSQueue in ActiveMQ, using ActiveMQ management console.
I am trying to produce a message in this queue using WSO2 ESB message producer. Below are the source of my producer.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JmsProducerTest" transports="http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="jms:/NewJMSQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl"/>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

but i am getting following ERROR in WSO2 ESB console

```
[2013-09-20 11:37:51,777] ERROR - BaseUtils JNDI lookup of name dynamicQueues/NewJMSQueue returned a org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue while a
 interface javax.jms.Destination was expected
[2013-09-20 11:37:51,777] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseTransportException: JNDI lookup of name dynamicQueues/NewJMSQueue returned a org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQ
ueue while a interface javax.jms.Destination was expected
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseUtils.handleException(BaseUtils.java:167)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookup(JMSUtils.java:522)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookupDestination(JMSUtils.java:718)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.getDestination(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:184)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.loadConnectionFactoryFromProperties(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:132)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:330)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:124)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:456)
```

Comment: Can you let us know the names list of jars included in ESB/repository/components/lib directory in your running ESB node? Thanks;

Answer (score 1):

I have added following jar files. geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1,jar hawtbuf-1.9.jar, activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar, activemq-client-5.8.0.jar, activemq-all-5.8.. 
once i removed activemq-all-5.8.0.jar it is working fine.